# I don't know why this web services does not work

Tags: java, web-services

This is a sample class

```
public class NewClass {
    public String hello1(String txt) {
        String a = "Hello " + txt + " !";
        return a;
    }
}
```

and this is a sample web service

```
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService2")
public class NewWebService2 {
    private NewClass newess;
    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello11")
    public String hello11(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        String ess=newess.hello1(txt);
        return ess;
    }

}
```

The first method `hello` works exactly but the second method `hello11` is not working. I don't understand the problem. The server shows this message:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
at newpackage.NewWebService2.hello11(NewWebService2.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:94)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
    .
    .
    .
```

please I need to understand this problem and how I can resolve it.

Comment: `newess` is `null`. Initialize it with `newess = new NewClass();`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your **NewClass newess**. You are trying to access newess.hello1() without initializing your newess variable

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
      this.newess = new NewClass();
```

This isn't thread safe.  The member variable is unnecessary.

Not good code, but I'm sure it's just a bad example.

Comment: in my project i will use spring framework so i will use @autowired to injec a class(@service) in my web services so i will use their method, my question it is true and the web service can work,  i need tutoriels or a sample example thanks for all

Comment: You're going to have trouble with Spring if this is your level of expertise with Java.  It's like putting a Ferrari in the hands of a small child.